# Docker image build ends up with dangling images

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV STAR_VERSION=2.7.3a
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y git-all \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential \
        && apt-get install -y make \
        && apt-get install -y libz.dev \
        && echo "downloading ${STAR_VERSION}"

WORKDIR /mnt/d/github/Docker/STAR_2.7.3a/

RUN git clone https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR.git \
        && cd STAR/source \
        && echo "making STAR ${STAR_VERSION}" \
        && make STAR

CMD ["STAR", "--version"]
```

Build image:

```
docker image build .
```

It showed it's successfully built (with some warnings though) but when I check it

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              e57297dc089d        29 minutes ago      1.41GB
<none>              <none>              8c4d6c6be0d2        About an hour ago   915MB
<none>              <none>              a2625623ebb7        2 hours ago         754MB
$ docker image ls --filter dangling=true
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              e57297dc089d        30 minutes ago      1.41GB
<none>              <none>              8c4d6c6be0d2        About an hour ago   915MB
<none>              <none>              a2625623ebb7        2 hours ago         754MB
```

Why are they all danging and no tags?

Comment: In order to answer this, you need to show us how you build your images (the command your enter in the prompt)

Comment: I have added `docker image build .`

Comment: You need `docker build -t tour_image_name:your_tag .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default, the images that you build from a *Dockerfile* are untagged, and unamed.

You need to pass a `repo:tag` as option to the build command in order to tag them.

```
docker image build --tag some/repo:tag .
```

From the documentation:

```
--tag , -t      Name and optionally a tag in the ‘name:tag’ format
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/

***Mind that:*** untagged images can also happen if you retag an another image with the same tag, so to say, stealing the tag from an existing image, leaving the old image untagged.

> This will display untagged images that are the leaves of the images
>   tree (not intermediary layers). These images occur when a new build of
>   an image takes the `repo:tag` away from the image ID, leaving it as
>   `<none>:<none>` or untagged. A warning will be issued if trying to
>   remove an image when a container is presently using it. By having this
>   flag it allows for batch cleanup.

*Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filtering*